# Pasar valor a input text dato que viene via ruta ajax (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo un select que cargo con datos desde una bd (funcionando ok), ahora debo mostrar en un select un dato en especial (responsable) en un input tipo text.

Tengo una function jquery que mediante ajax obtiene un dato en concreto (nombre del responsable segun el id del item que selecciono en el select de mas arriba) pero no me resulta mostrar el nombre del responsable (la ruta trae el dato correctamente, y lo mas que he conseguido es mostrar el id del select en el textbox)

Mi funcion jquery es esta:

```
                    $('#bodega_origen').on('change', function(){
                    var id = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                            url:"{{ url('/bodResp') }}"+`/${id}`,
                            method:"get",
                            //data:{select:select, value:value, dependent:dependent},
                            success:function(result)
                            {

                                var data = result.data;
                                console.log(data)
                                //var responsable = $(this).val();
                                //$("#responsable_origen").html(result.data);
                               //var opciones = '';
                               //result.data.forEach(element => {

                                 //  opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.responsable}</option>`;
                               //});
                               $('#responsable_origen').val($(this).val());
                               //$("#servicio_id").append(opciones);
                            }
                        })


                });
```

Saludos a todos y gracias

Comment: Muestra el código donde se hace la consulta también

Comment: esta es la funcion (la tengo en mi controlador):  public function getResponsable($id){
        $responsable = Bodega::find($id)->responsable;
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $responsable
        ], 200);
    }

Comment: @NicolasAlmonacid No he probado el código ni nada, solo te comento por encima: creo que tu error es que estás usando `this` (en la respuesta de *ajax*, `$('#responsable_origen').val($(this).val())`) cuando `this` hace referencia al *scope* de la *function*. Prueba de usar una *arrow function*, `... success: result => { ... }`.

Comment: @VRoxa no entendi bien,

Comment: Convierte la *function* a *arrow function*, sustituye `success:function(result)` por `success: result =>`.

Comment: @VRoxa substituyendo como em comentas me pasa el id(numero) al input,

Comment: analizando, la ruta del ajax lo unico que me devuelve es esto: {"data":"Sergio Ojeda"}, no calificaria como array por lo cual tal vez no estoy por el camino correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resuelto, finalmente utilize

```
dataType: "json",
                success: function (jdata) {
                    var jsonData=jdata
                    console.log(jsonData)
                    //alert(jsonData.data);
                    $('#responsable_origen').val(jsonData.data);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos.**

Te sugiero agregar el `<option>` de la [siguiente forma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery):

```
// Si realizas varias veces el llamado al AJAX te sugiero antes del forEach limpiar el servicio_id
result.data.forEach(element => {
  // Asumo que servicio_id es el identificador de un componente tipo select
  $("#servicio_id").append(new Option(element.responsable, element.id));
});
```

Comment: hola roberto, entiendo que de esta manera estaria obteniendo tanto el id como el texto de la opcion que seleccione del select?